# Image of chart has black background (Chart.js v4.3.0)

Tags: chart.js

When I copy the image of the chart rendered, I get the background as black. Is there a way to change it to white or any other color I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using Canvas and the afterRender hook. Create your plugin with the `afterRender` hook which when called gets the canvas of the chart.js element, and changes its `fillStyle`.

The plugin:

```js
const plugin = {
    id: 'after-render',
    
    afterRender: (c) => {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('containerId').getContext('2d');
        ctx.save();
        // The next line is essential to prevent unusual behavior.
        // As it causes the whole chart to go blank, when removed
        // Technique is taken from:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/50126796/165164
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
};
```

Change `containerId` to what you passed as the id in the html canvas tag.

And then, pass this plugin in the `plugins` option in the Chart constructor:

```js
    new Chart(document.getElementById('consumptions'), {
        // ... options
        plugins: [plugin],
    })
};
```